# Loading AJAX on page that already have been "AJAX'ed"

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have script that loads content into a DIV via AJAX by adding #link string into address:

```
function loadPage(url) {        
    ajaxURL = document.URL;
    splitedAjaxURL = ajaxURL.split('#');

    url = url.replace('#page','');  
    $('#loading').css('display','block');   
    $.ajax( { type: "POST",
              url: "ajax_loader.cfm",
              data: 'page='+url,
              dataType: "html",
              success: function(msg) {
                  if(parseInt(msg) != 0) {
              $('#pageContent').html(msg);
              $('#loading').css('display','none');
          }
       } 
    });
}
```

On that page I have a select drop down that allows user to chose how many items to display (10, 20, 40, 70.. etc..). This select is inside a form whose action is `abc.cfm`, that was already loaded into `content.cfm` via an AJAX request.

How can I attach the select action to AJAX? Currently when I select an option, it opens `abc.cfm` as a separate page. But I need it to be inside `content.cfm`, like in my first request.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not what you want, but:

```
function loadPage(url)
  {

      ajaxURL = document.URL;
      splitedAjaxURL = ajaxURL.split('#');
      url=url.replace('#page','');
      data = {
        "page":url,
        "select_id": $("#your_select_id").val(),
      };
      $('#loading').css('display','block'); 
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_loader.cfm",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg){
 if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
     {
      $('#pageContent').html(msg);
      $('#loading').css('display','none');
     }
  }
 });
```

On the server side, you need to json -decod the posted value!